# How to make windows 10 like notifications menu in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, gsap

I'm working on a web app and I'd like to achieve [this effect](https://gyazo.com/7d71948650426748856cd96d8a93c65b). The idea is that when I click a button it toggles between showing the menu and not showing it. What I'm specially interested in is that transparent blur effect you see in the body of the menu, where you see what's behind it, but blurry. I'm using both jQuery and GSAP in my web app, so if you'd like to use that in your solution, you are more than welcome to.

If anyone could explain me how to do it I'd be very grateful. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is a windows charms. You can create it with Metro 4 Library:

Docs: https://metroui.org.ua/charms.html
Demo: https://metroui.org.ua/feature-demo/desktop/

Comment: You can view source code for this demo on GitHub https://github.com/olton/Metro-UI-CSS/tree/4.2.35/docs/examples/desktop

Answer (score -1):

this would help https://metroui.org.ua/
or google metro css

Comment: what i actually wanted to know is how to accomplish that transparent blurriness without more frameworks. Do you know if it's possible?

Comment: css -> filter: blur(5px)

Comment: the first is transparency the second is blur filter

Comment: thank you! Why did this get 3 downvotes? Was it a bad question?

Comment: i dont know thats strange, and also downvotes without comments suck

Comment: I know they should add that I'm gonna suggest it